# Getting the package name that contains a library that I need

Tags: linux, package-management, yum

Fedora 14

I recently went to install some software using the source files.

When I ran the command

```
./configure
```

I got a message saying that

```
No package gthread-2.0 not found
```

After searching the internet some one had the same problem. I needed to install a package called

```
glib2-devel
```

However, rather that searching the internet. Is there any yum command that can give me that information?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum whatprovides '*/pkgconfig/gthread-2.0.pc'
```

Comment: How is this different from mine? Or you didn't notice it? Also, not all libraries have a `.pc` file.

Comment: @Tshepang: It will look for the exact pkgconfig file that the configure routine in the question is looking for, instead of trying to search by a virtual provides *which may or may not* match the name it is looking for.

Comment: You mind explaining that on the answer itself. What if the asker doesn't know what pkgconfig is.

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum whatprovides "*gthread-2.0*"`. ([via](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/how-to-find-out-which-package-a-file-belongs-to))